# Saying "favorite dish(es) to cook" in another way

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm having trouble saying "favorite dish(es) to cook" in a more concise manner. One or two words would be preferred!

Ex:
I hope to hope to try my friend's ______ at the potluck tomorrow!

Comment: Do what English speakers do and shorten it. _I hope to try my friends **favorites** at the potluck tomorrow._

Comment: 'Specialities' (UK) / 'specialties' (US) is probably largely synonymous.